# Google Analytics not firing?

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following code in my website and its not firing an event :

```
<li><a href="/customer-care/faq" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'FOOTER MENU', 'CLICK', 'FAQs']);" target="_blank">FAQs</a></li>
```

I have the following code in the same page and I am getting an event back for it :

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="PopupCenter('/privacy_policy.aspx','','550','700')">Privacy Policy</a></li>
```

why won't my first line of code fire an event on google analytics ?

Comment: Can you please help ?

Comment: Can you share your website? It would help with troubleshooting. Are you using classic GA or Universal Analytics?

Comment: website is www.darkrome.com  I have a option called tracking info in Property under admin so it is Universal Analytics account

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Universal Analytics, but the onclick code you have is for Classic GA. You will need to update the onclick code as follows:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'FOOTER MENU', 'CLICK', 'FAQs');"
```